# how i do the page linking in Sdl Tridion? please give the example

Tags: content-delivery, publishing, templating, linking

I am new in sdl tridion.and I am creating a web site on sdl tridion and i create a navigation menu.and I have  anchor tag in this menu .How i give the page path on the anchor tag property href.

Comment: how are you generating the navigation menu? please explain so that you can get a good answer. If are using a XML(published from Tridion) to generate it, you can include the published path of the page to the XML same way as page titles.

Comment: code samples, +1.  The Tridion 'Linking API' uses the Page (or Component) URI to find the page.  Advantage is that no 404s (returns empty string if not found).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How i attach Navigation menu on each pages on Sdl Tridion and how i display pages on click of navigation menu tab?](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4711/how-i-attach-navigation-menu-on-each-pages-on-sdl-tridion-and-how-i-display-page)

Comment: I really cannot make anything from this question, can you please edit the question and try to explain what your issue is? You do not have to indicate that you are new to SDL Tridion (that much is already obvious), but you do need to mention information like where are you trying to generate these links, is it in a Page Template, or is it perhaps on the website itself? Also do mention what language you are using (like DWT or Razor for a Template or ASP.NET or JSP for the website). Right now you tagged your question with both Content Delivery and Templating, that is rather distracting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at the documentation for the `<tridion:PageLink>` control (or JSP tag) on [SDL LiveContent](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-34A56889-79EE-4B3A-878A-B8FE111637D6) (login required).

Since you don't give much more details about how you're generating the links, and whether this is code that runs on CM at publish time or CD at render time, I can't expand much more than this...

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating a navigation menu you have multiple options and you have to decide one based on your requirement (eg. structure group, taxonomy based). You can check this[link](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-055D20C7-BDBC-4425-820D-7A741531EFAF&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-055D20C7-BDBC-4425-820D-7A741531EFAF.xml&resource=&inner_id=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-055D20C7-BDBC-4425-820D-7A741531EFAF&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql?c=t&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US&action=search&query=site%2520map&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1394112862993&currentQuery=site%2520map&currentScope=)

The link describes how you can create navigation for your website but for both the approaches you will have to write a c# TBB to push link in your sitemap. sample TBB which you can use can be downloaded from [here](https://sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/generic-2011-tbbs.aspx)